# Ideas for "Raspberry Office Mascot"

Tags: pi-3

Santa Claus brought me Raspberry Pi 3 this year and I'd like to use it in my workplace. I work as Test Developer in a small, start-up company and I guess it's a great opportunity to use my gift in work and improve quality of the software that we're developing.

So, I'm going to connect traffic light to Raspberry and integrate with Jenkins. I was thinking about writing an application to show statistics of git and display them on the screen. Also, I have an idea to implement a limited voice assistant to ask for example who should start the daily :)

Do you have more ideas how can I use Raspberry in work to make my workplace greater?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be getting down-votes, and this isn't really a great question for SE, but what you're asking about -- interfacing the RPi to physical indicators of some sort -- is definitely on-topic. If you can frame your question(s) in more specific RPi interfacing terms, you'll get better responses.

It would be fairly straightforward to interface the RPi to some sort of hardware -- check out [Google's Paper Signals](https://papersignals.withgoogle.com/) for inspiration -- to indicate all sorts of status. While Paper Signals is based on Arduino controllers, you could use the RPi for the same or even more sophisticated status indicators. There are projects using the RPi to provide visual feedback on bus arrivals, traffic loading, bathroom availability and a host of other topics that might be useful and even fun in your office. Tying it into your actual development process adds some legitimacy to the project.

Break it into sub-projects:

1. Tying Jenkins and other software tools together with the RPi. I'd suggest looking at MQTT as a simple way of "wiring" systems together via networks simply.
2. Interfacing the RPi to your display. Being in a start-up, I'm going to assume you've got talent around that you could hand the status data off to and work it into a nice dashboard display of git stats.
3. Interfacing the RPi to hardware. There are a wealth of projects around on interfacing the low (3.3v) RPi GPIO pins to higher-voltage physical devices safely. You'll need to learn some rudimentary electronics, but it's not overly complex.

As you dive in, come back and as more detailed RPi-specific questions and you should get some more helpful answers. If you just want to kick around ideas, someplace like the [raspberry_pi subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/) might be more appropriate.